# Tricky problem with sources in list of figures

Tags: captions, subfloats, tocloft, subcaption

I've a very tricky problem here:

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,german]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}
                \caption{Caption1}
        \end{subfigure}%
        ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc.
          %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}
                \caption{Caption2}
        \end{subfigure}
        ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc.
          %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}
                \caption{Caption3}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Caption0}
\end{figure}
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

## Problem:

I need to have my sources of the images in the list of figures. The caption for the figure **must** be under the image (bottom).

## What I need:

```
     List of Figures

1    Caption ............................................. 1
     (a)    Caption1 ..................................... 2
            Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com
     (b)    Caption2 ..................................... 3
            Source: StackExchange
            Graphic: Severin
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Are you using [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)?

Comment: @Werner
In this MWE I'm not using tocloft, but I have also tried with tocloft, subfigures, etc. ...

Comment: @Werner
The "Caption" has no source, the source is printed below the "subcaption". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you plan to have subcaptions that split across lines?

Comment: @egreg
What do you mean by "split across lines"? If you mean a caption which has a multiple lines (\newline), I think I need that.